# Latex not finding 'mhchem.sty'

Tags: texlive

I just installed a new copy of latex 2015 from the latex site, i.e., not from the Ubuntu distro, and configured tlmgr. I'm getting an error that 'mhchem.sty' is not found however file is located in:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mhchem/mhchem.sty
```

What have I done wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: The `mhchem.sty` file is included in the `texlive-science` package in recent ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the database of the installed packages with the command `texhash` in a terminal.

Comment: This didn't work until I copied the .sty file from the /usr/local/.... directory to my own ~/texmf/tex/latex/ directory.  Then running texhash seemed to help.  Also error was coming from within texmaker, read somewhere else that PATH settings for texlive have to be set in .profile, and not in .bashrc, or will not affect texmaker.  Eventually got it working but perhaps texlive install instructions are incorrect with respect to .bashrc?  Tx. J

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has been downvoted, because it is the *correct* one. Maybe adding that `texhash` (or the equivalent `mktexlsr`) command has to be run as superuser.